# Creating dynamic coordinate vectors

Tags: modeling, constraints, vector

1. I would like to make an animation similar to [this one](https://streamable.com/gxvcxs)(This was made on [manim](https://github.com/3b1b/manim)). The white line from the origin should be a 3D arrow object tracking the position of the blue cube at every key frame.(The cube moves along some predetermined path in 3D space).

Block at some position in 3D space at time **t**.
[image]

Block at a different position in time **t + delta t**
[image]

I am new to blender and I can only draw the different objects for now but I am getting stuck on creating the constraints necessary so that the arrow changes its length(scale along the length) to where the cube is located.

2. As an addition, I would like the arrow(both its tail and head) to scale proportionally when the arrow length is between 0 and 1 unit, [like so](https://streamable.com/shf1c2).
   The images below show how the vector should scale(in 3D though).

Only scale the tail on its longitudinal axis for vector lengths greater than 1 unit
[image: Only scale the tail on its longitudinal axis for vector lengths greater than 1 unit]

When the vector length in below 1 unit, scale both the tail and the head
[image]

Vector length goes to zero as the position of tracked object gets closer to the origin.
[image]

Comment: Hi. While videos can be good, ideally all question content should be in the question body, in the form of good descriptions of the issue and images. Thanks.

Comment: @RayMairlot, Thank you for the pointer. I have tried to improve it by adding the images.